# How to load a custom .pbf file in ngx-openlayers

Tags: javascript, angular, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I was able to load maps using the [ngx-openlayers](https://github.com/quentin-ol/ngx-openlayers) with the following code

```
   <aol-map [width]="'100%'" [height]="'100%'">
      <aol-view [zoom]="zoom">
        <aol-coordinate [x]="5" [y]="45" [srid]="'EPSG:4326'"></aol-coordinate>
      </aol-view>
      <aol-layer-tile [opacity]="opacity">
        <aol-source-osm></aol-source-osm>
      </aol-layer-tile>
      <aol-layer-vector [opacity]="opacity">
        <aol-source-vector>
          <aol-feature>
            <aol-geometry-point>
              <aol-coordinate [x]="5" [y]="45" [srid]="'EPSG:4326'"></aol-coordinate>
            </aol-geometry-point>
            <aol-style>
              <aol-style-circle [radius]="10">
                <aol-style-stroke [color]="'black'" [width]="width"></aol-style-stroke>
                <aol-style-fill [color]="'green'"></aol-style-fill>
              </aol-style-circle>
            </aol-style>
          </aol-feature>
          <aol-feature>
            <aol-geometry-point>
              <aol-coordinate [x]="5.1" [y]="45.1" [srid]="'EPSG:4326'"></aol-coordinate>
            </aol-geometry-point>
            <aol-style>
              <aol-style-icon [src]="'assets/marker.png'" [anchor]="[0.5, 1]" [anchorXUnits]="'fraction'" [anchorYUnits]="'fraction'" [scale]="0.1"
                [anchorOrigin]="'top-left'">
              </aol-style-icon>
            </aol-style>
          </aol-feature>
        </aol-source-vector>
      </aol-layer-vector>
    </aol-map>
```

My issue is I want to load a custom map location that I have served on my local machine using MapTile server on http://localhost:8090/tileserver.php#trails/ol3 URL. 
Now the XYZ URL from the above server is (http://localhost:8090/tileserver.php?/index.json?/trails/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf)

How can I load this map using the ngx-openlayers packkage

I have tried to use this but it is not working

```
<aol-map [width]="'500px'" [height]="'300px'">
        <aol-interaction-default></aol-interaction-default>
        <aol-control-defaults></aol-control-defaults>
        <aol-control-fullscreen></aol-control-fullscreen>
        <aol-layer-tile>
        <aol-source-osm></aol-source-osm>
        <aol-source-xyz [url]="'http://localhost:8090/tileserver.php?/index.json?/trails/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'">
        </aol-source-xyz>
        </aol-layer-tile>

        <aol-view [zoom]="12">
        <aol-coordinate [x]="6.47" [y]="53.44" [srid]="'EPSG:4326'"></aol-coordinate>
        </aol-view>
        </aol-map>
```

Comment: [PBF](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format) is the file format of raw OSM vector data. A [tile](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) server needs raster images instead (which can be produced by *rendering* PBF data).

Comment: Thanks, I get it now but how can PBF data can be rendered? is it at runtime? or there is a tool I can use to generate the .png without losing the folder structure? or use mbtiles?

Comment: [Rendering](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) needs a [tile server](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) to do it on the fly or some software like Maperitive or TileMill to do it beforehand. mbtiles will work, too. They contain pre-rendered tiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah I'm about to answer my own question cause it might help someone in the future.

**The Basics**

There are two broad classifications for maps from OSM (OpenStreetMap)

1.Raster Format: This one is the raster image (PNG, JPEG, SVG ...) tiles for the map. This format can be compressed and put it to .mbtiles format.
You can use tools like [mbuilt](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) to extract the contents into the tms, wsm or XYZ folder structure. This one is the easy and faster option.

2. Vector Format: This one is a Vector file format it can have multiple file type like .pbf inside it. It can also be compressed into a .mbtiles file. we need a tile server to render the contents of the vector files.
   [Tile server GL](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl) is a tile server to serve both vector/raster map files (mbtiles)

After solving the offline hosting issue, I have used a default leaflet.js package for angular and everything worked fine without an issue.

I used [OpenMaptiles](https://openmaptiles.com) map files to host them using the tileserver-gl